# Expected value of stock prices

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose the the value of an stock is $S_t = S_{t-1}exp(\mu +\sigma Z_t) $ where at time 0, $S = S_0$ and $Z_t$ are i.i.d standard normal random variables.

Need to find the E($S_1$),E($S_2$), E($S_2|S_1$).

For E($S_1$):
E($S_1$)

= E($S_0$exp($\mu +\sigma Z_1$))

= $S_0exp(u)$*$exp(\sigma Z_1)$

Since the mgf of $exp(\sigma Z_1)$ = $exp(1/2 \sigma^2)$

=$S_0exp(u)$*$exp(1/2 \sigma^2)$

= $S_0exp(u+1/2 \sigma^2)$

E($S_2$)

= E($S_0*exp(\mu +\sigma Z_1)*$exp($\mu +\sigma Z_2$))

=$S_0*exp(2\mu)*exp(\sigma Z_1)*exp(\sigma Z_2)$

= $S_0*exp(2\mu)*exp(\sigma Z_1+\sigma Z_2)$

= $S_0*exp(2\mu)*exp(\sigma^2)$

Not sure how to start on $E(S_2|S_1)$? Need some help on starting on that...

Comment: Hint: ${\rm E}[XY\mid \mathcal{F}]=X{\rm E}[Y\mid \mathcal{F}]$ if $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Comment: So it becomes $S_1E(exp(\mu +\sigma Z_t)|S_1) =S_1*E(exp(\mu +\sigma Z_t) = S_1*exp(u+1/2 \sigma^2)$ ?

Comment: Replace $Z_t$ by $Z_1$, but else it's fine. (Note you're using the independence of $Z_1$ and $Z_0$ since conditioning on $S_1$ is the same as conditioning on $Z_0$).

Comment: didn't get your last point..

Comment: the first two are ok?

Comment: In order for you to conclude that ${\rm E}[\exp(\mu+\sigma Z_1)\mid S_1]={\rm E}[\exp(\mu+\sigma Z_1)]$ you must have that $\exp(\mu+\sigma Z_1)$ is independent of $S_1$. But $S_1=S_0\exp(\mu+\sigma Z_0)$ which is just a function of $Z_0$ (I assume that $S_0$ is a constant), and since we know that $Z_1$ and $Z_0$ are independent all is good.